# Adjusting the height of norm symbol

Tags: symbols

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{times,fancyhdr,lastpage,parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate,amsbsy,amsthm}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathbf}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb} 

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}

\Vert \frac{\mf{F}^{-1}(\mf{y} + \mf{k}) - \mf{F}^{-1}(\mf{y}) - A^{-1}\mf{k}}{\Vert \mf{k} \Vert} \Vert

\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The code `\Vert` for norm is not cover the fraction. I have tried to use `\left|\left|` and `\right|\right|` then finally the norm can cover the fraction. But is there have any other solution to cover the fraction like directly use `\norm`?

Comment: `\left\Vert` and `\right\Vert`

Comment: See also the `mathtools` package and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` for a useful way to defined a `\norm` command. Note that is is **not** recommended to always autocase fences.

Comment: please test your code before posting `\begin[a` would give an error, as would blank lines in math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the comments below your question, a possible solution to your problem is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathbf}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}

\begin{document}
\[
\norm*{\frac{\mf{F}^{-1}(\mf{y} + \mf{k}) - \mf{F}^{-1}(\mf{y}) - A^{-1}\mf{k}}
            {\norm*{\mf{k}}}
        } 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or in case, that you not like to use @daleif advice, you can wrote:

```
\[
\left\Vert \frac{\mf{F}^{-1}(\mf{y} + \mf{k}) - \mf{F}^{-1}(\mf{y}) - A^{-1}\mf{k}}{\Vert \mf{k} \Vert} \right\Vert
\]
```

Result is the same.

**Edit**
Corrected is definition of `\norm`. Now not consider some options to delimiter.

Comment: Got it, just define a new command for norm, thanks sir.

Comment: @RotiCanai, than you can accept my answer (by clicking on check mark at top left side of the answer).

Comment: In your case is sufficient to define `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert`. In the cases when you like to add some optional argument than use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert` For details see ˙mathtools` package documentation, page 26. I will correct answer accordingly.